# <Yes, I do> while answering a "do question"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm curious about knowing the reason why we say "**I do**" after "*Yes*" while answering a "*do question*".

Let's look at the following example:

> Question: *Do you speak English?*
>
> Answer 1: *Yes* 
>  Answer 2: *Yes, I do* 
> Answer 3: *Yes, I speak*

The answer 1 is clear, nothing to ask about it. It's the same for answer 3.

But in the answer 2, why do we add "*I do*". What is the reason for doing so?
What's the meaning of "*I do*". I wonder if "*Yes, I do*" expresses "*Yes, I speak*".

Could you please clarify that for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do* can stand for a whole verb phrase: it is sometimes called a "pro-verb" (different from a "proverb"!) on the analogy of a "pronoun"

Note that your *Yes, I speak* is not grammatical: *speak* in the sense of "talk in a particular language" **requires** an object. You could say *yes, I speak it* (though that doesn't sound very natural to me). If we wanted to repeat *speak*, we would say *Yes, I speak English*.

But much more natural is to use the pro-verb *do*, which can stand for a whole predicate (verb and objects or complements).

So in summary, we can say:

> Yes.
>
> Yes, I speak English.
>
> ? Yes, I speak it. (there are probably contexts where this does occur, but not normally).
>
> Yes, I do.

Note that we *can't* give the pro-verb *do* an object, unless for contrast or emphasis:

> ? Yes, I do English. This sounds odd, except in contexts like the following:
>
> Do you speak German?
>
> No, but I do English.